# warning massage from aggregateDist in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use function `aggregateDist` from package `actuar` in R.

First I used function `discretize` for Patero distribtion with parameters 6 and 500

```
f <- discretize(
    cdf =ppareto(x,6,500), 
    from = 0, 
    to = 100, 
    step=1, 
    method="lower"
    )
```

and then I apllied function `aggregateDist` to `f` as

```
 F <- aggregateDist(
    method = "recursive", 
    model.freq = "geometric", 
    model.sev = f, 
    prob = 0.6,
   )
```

I get a following warning:

```
Warning message:
In panjer(fx = model.sev, dist = dist, p0 = p0, x.scale = x.scale,  :
  maximum number of recursions reached before the probability distribution was complete
```

Why is this warning appearing? Should I ignore this massage and just use produced data? Or what should I do?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am also using the actuar package to measure VaR, TVaR, etc and I had the same problem.
You should lower the steps as it seems that it fails with large numbers of claims.
The following info was found in the 'actuar' package notes. [Source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/actuar/actuar.pdf)

*The recursion will fail to start if the expected number of claims is too large. One may divide the
appropriate parameter of the frequency distribution by 2
n and convolve the resulting distribution
n = convolve times.*

Sorry for the late reply

Comment: In the quote should be "...frequency distribution by 2^n..."